# Update collection when update entity from it in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have **children** list (reducer) and **families** list (reducer). The **families** list contains **array of children**.

How to update the child in the family's **array of children** when update a child from the **children** list using Redux?

This is my children reducer update case:

```js
export function children(state = [], action) {
    // ...

    case types.UPDATE_CHILD: {
        const childIndex = state.findIndex(child => child.id === action.id);
        state[childIndex] = action.updatedChild;
        return state;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When redux action fired, by default it goes through all of the reducers.

In general reducer architecture, we use something like { switch } syntax, and if the reducer don't have a responded { case } to the action, the action will go through { default } option in reducer.

---

```
 const actionA = payload => (dispatch, getState) => dispatch({ type: 'a', payload })

 const reducerA = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'a':
        // action will be reduced here
        return action.payload
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

 const reducerB = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'b':
        return action.payload
    default:
        // action will be reduced here
        return state;
  }
}
```

---

Therefore, just add { types.UPDATE_CHILD } case at family reducer.

---

```
const reducerB = (state = {}, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
     case 'b':
         return action.payload
     case 'a':
         // now action will be reduced here
         return action.payload
     default:
         return state;
   }
 }
```

---

Another thing about your reducer, that is you manipulate state directly at the reducer and not at the return, change it to -

---

```
      case types.UPDATE_CHILD: {
       return state.filter(child => child.id === action.id ? action.updatedChild : child);
}
```

Comment: It should be .map, not .filter